# Use an injecting variable in advice AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj, aspect

Please i try to add the variable *time* to the exestant class *Connection* with AspectJ, and it works, but when i try to use it in an advice Before i have this error : *cannot be resolved to a variable*
This is my code :

```
public privileged aspect TimeManagement {
pointcut constConnection() : 
    execution(telecom.v2.connect.Connection.new(..));

pointcut completepc() : execution(* 
   telecom.v2.connect.Connection.complete()) ;

Timer Connection.timer; // here i define my variable in connection

after():constConnection(){
    timer = new Timer();
}

after():completepc(){       
    timer.start(); // here i use it but the error is appeared 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved ;)

```
  pointcut completePc() : execution(* telecom.v2.connect.Connection.complete()) ;

  after(Connection connection):completePc() && this(connection) {

    connection.timer.start();
}
```